# Deep copy of "temporary object" in C++

Tags: c++, object, stl, deep-copy

I have defined a Node struct:

```
struct Node {
   char val;
   bool isEnd;
   Node* childs[26];
   Node* getChild(char c) {
       return childs[c - 'a'];
   }
   Node getChild1(char c) {
       return *childs[c - 'a'];
   }
};
```

Now in order to search through the sub-tree of this node, I defined a searchSubTree() function, as below:

```
void searchSubTree(string word, Node* cur) {
   for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
       ...
       cur = cur->getChild(word[i]);
   }
}
```

This all works fine, because Node* cur is a pointer, and I am using "cur" variable to temporarily points to a node and its child.

However, how should I be able to avoid using the "temporary" pointer and use a temporary object in each iteration instead? I know that just using the Node::getChild1() signature is not enough, because in the line:

```
cur = cur.getChild1(word[i])
```

This will result in a shallow copy of "cur", and update actual content of each node, whereas I only want cur to be temporary so that it can iterate through each child. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why does getChild1 return a copy and not the pointer?

Comment: `Node getChild1(char c)` seems to be a dangerous operation.

Comment: It sounds silly but I am trying to avoid pointer outside Node class, and see if it can work well @manni66

Comment: I agree, how should I properly define getChild1() to make it work as I expected?

Comment: @jer_yin Are you sure about `Node* childs[26];`? Shouldn't that rather be `Node childs[26];`?

Comment: @user0042 Yes I am sure about the childs array here. Node* childs[26] is only consuming 26 pointer space of memory, and I can allocate for a node when I have to. However by doing Node childs[26], I am allocating 26 nodes at one time, some of that might never be used, so the space can be wasted.

Comment: @jer_yin Well, you can implement  `const Node& getChild1(char c)` if you want to avoid these _deep copies_ (which they aren't actually) and avoid using pointers.

Comment: Ahhh, I got it, define childs as actually nodes instead of pointers, this way the assignment will make cur act as a "temporary object". Thanks! @user0042